# ¿Como Unir Dos Consultas Pero Son De Diferentes Bases De Datos En Laravel 7?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Quisiera que me ayudarán para poder hacer este proceso **ya que tengo dos bases distintas**, y tengo que hacer consultas en ella para mostrar los datos pero no se si sea posible comparar datos de esas consultas y es que tengo que visualizar si los correos de la tabla1 que esta en base 1 son iguales a la tabla2 de la base de datos 2 y de ahi mostrarlos a la vista. Pero no tengo idea de como poder realizarlo.
Gracias.

Comment: Considera que te pueden cerrar la pregunta pues solo expones lo que intentas lograr pero no aquello que has intentado, sugiero leas [ask], por otro lado no hace falta el uso de mayúsculas sostenidas, lo cual sería casi *gritar*

Comment: son dos bases de datos distintas las los son derivadas de mysql

Answer (score 1):

**1. Base Teórica**

Para ponernos de acuerdo con la terminología, en MySQL se le suele llamar "base de datos" a lo que en realidad es un schema. Estos schemas son un espacio de nombres o una agrupación lógica pero, para todo otro efecto, sus tablas, vistas, funciones, triggers, índices, constraints, pulpos pegajosos y espadas de He-Man, se gestionan en el mismo INFORMATION SCHEMA. El único aspecto en donde hay granularidad estructural es en los permisos de usuario. En ese aspecto sí es posible que dos schemas en la misma base de datos sean completamente opacos entre sí dependiendo de cuán específicos sean los permisos de usuario.

Recalco lo anterior porque si en tu escenario estamos hablando de dos modelos que residen casa uno en distintos schemas (y por tanto se acceden mediante distinta conexión en Laravel) pero siempre **en el mismo servidor de BBDD**, y cuentas con **un usuario que tiene permiso para ver ambos schemas**, (aunque ahora lo tengas configurado con usuarios distintos), entonces podemos proceder al punto **2**. En cualquier otro caso, podemos pasar al punto **4**

**2. Caso Práctico**

Supongamos un schema `comercial` y un schema `marketing`. La primera tiene una tabla `clientes` que son todas las personas que al momento de comprar  acceden a dejar su correo. La segunda tiene una tabla `contactos` que son personas que han respondido algún formulario, encuesta o correo. La empresa lanzará su propia tarjeta de crédito y se ha determinado que los correos que se hallan en ambas tablas conforman un grupo con altas probabilidades de suscribir este medio de pago.

A nivel de base de datos, ambas tablas tienen un índice único en el campo email, y se cruzan con una consulta del tipo:

```
 SELECT * FROM comercial.clientes 
   JOIN marketing.contactos USING (email)
```

En otras palabras, es lo mismo que una consulta corriente, excepto que se  prefija el nombre de la tabla con el nombre del schema. Insisto, esto es viable solamente si se ejecuta con un usuario que pueda ver ambos schemas.

**3 Llevándolo a Laravel**

Si lo haces con el query builder, la consulta que puse más arriba puedes ejecutarla tal como puse, sustituyendo los nombres de schemas y tablas para tu caso de uso.

Si no tuvieras certeza del nombre de los schemas, por ejemplo porque no se llaman exactamente igual en los ambientes de desarrollo, staging, y producción, o simplemente porque te resulta engorroso tener que incluir el nombre del schema en todas partes, es posible encapsular esta lógica para que el mismo modelo tenga esa responsabilidad:

- Los modelos saben cómo se llama su tabla y cómo se llama su conexión.
- mediante el nombre de la conexión, y usando el helper `config` se puede determinar el nombre del schema.

Si se modifica el constructor de ambos modelos como sigue:

```
public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
{
    $connection = $this->connection ?? config('database.default');
    $this->table = \sprintf(
            '%s.%s',
            config(\sprintf('database.connections.%s.database', $connection)),
            $this->table
        );
    }
    parent::__construct($attributes);
}
```

Sería lo mismo que el modelo Clientes en vez de decir

```
 protected $table = 'clientes';
```

Dijera

```
 protected $table = 'comercial.clientes';
```

Y lo mismo con `marketing.contactos`.

Con esto podrás declarar una relación común y corriente. En el modelo `Contacto`:

```
  public function cliente() {
       return $this->hasOne(\App\Models\Cliente::class, 'email', 'email');
  }
```

Y la relación inversa en el modelo Cliente

```
  public function contacto() {
       return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\Contacto::class, 'email', 'email');
  }
```

Evidentemente la noción de que un contacto tenga un cliente, o que un cliente pertenezca a un contacto es puramente ficticia, es una relación instrumental que nos permite consultar, por ejemplo

```
  Contacto::query()->with('cliente')
                   ->whereHas('cliente')
                   ->get([las columnas que te interesan]);
```

Lo único tedioso es que el resultado será una colección en donde cada item representará un contacto con una propiedad  `cliente` anidada, asi que te tocará mapear la colección resultante para entregársela a la vista.

---

**4 Usando Colecciones**

Ya que igual terminamos usando colecciones, posiblemente sea mejor cortar por lo sano y de plano olvidarse de la solución con Eloquent, optando en cambio por traer todo el contenido del modelo y haciendo el cruce en la capa de negocios.

```
$clientes = Cliente::all( )->keyBy('email');
$contactos = Contactos::all( )->keyBy('email');
$interseccion = $clientes->intersectByKeys($contactos);
```

(A menos que tengas 5 millones de correos en cada tabla y sea impracticable)